# JsonParseException while parsing from String to Map

Tags: java, json, jsp, freemarker, gson

I have done Map object to string object conversion like this

```
    public String getJsonString(Map<String, Map<String,List<CalculateContentCount>>> countMap) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(countMap);
    return jsonString;
}
```

In ftl I have set the returned String object into request and pased it into the JSP file

```
   <#assign countMap = json>
   <form action="/alfresco/jsp/kpub/reports/exportContentCountList.jsp" method="get">

<input type="hidden" name="countMap" id="countMap" value="${countMap}">
<input type="submit" value="ExportFiletoCSV"/>
   </form>
```

In exportContentCountList, I tried to parse the string object back to Map object,

```
String jsonString = request.getParameter("countMap");
System.out.println("jsonString : "+jsonString);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String,Map<String,List<CalculateContentCount>>> countMap = null;
Type type = null;
if(jsonString != null && !"".equals(jsonString)) {
    type = new TypeToken<Map<String,Map<String,List<CalculateKpubContentCount>>>>(){}.getType();
    countMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString,type);
}
```

While executing, following exception occurs. Here's the exceptiom

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Failed parsing JSON source:        
caused by:
com.google.gson.ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 1. 
Was expecting one of: 
<IDENTIFIER_SANS_EXPONENT> ... 
<IDENTIFIER_STARTS_WITH_EXPONENT> ... 
<SINGLE_QUOTE_LITERAL> ... 
<DOUBLE_QUOTE_LITERAL> ... 
"}" ...
```

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the generated HTML output. Rightclick page in webbrowser and choose *View Source*. Does it look right? Also the double quotes? Gson output JSON strings with double quotes. In other words, the generated HTML is syntactically invalid.

Use JSTL `fn:escapeXml()` to escape HTML special characters like `<`, `>`, `"`, `'` so that they won't malform the HTML syntax.

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<input type="hidden" name="countMap" id="countMap" value="${fn:escapeXml(countMap)}">
```

This way the entire string will be passed back instead of only a part until the first quote (which caused Gson to detect an EOF (End Of File, or better to be interpreted as End Of String).

---

**Update**:

If you can't use JSTL, you have to use `String#replace()` to escape HTML entities manually. E.g.

```
return jsonString.replace("\"", "&quot;");
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am using FTL which doesn't support tag libs. So I cant use the above. so i have passed the value lik value=${countMap}, without quotes, now it parses partially and shows me another error,

Comment: Output : jsonString : {"12/06/2010":{"kpubType":[{"count":0,"contentName":"Sanple"}]},"12/07/2010":{"topic":[{"count":0,"contentName":"Sample

Comment: After this error occurs, "com.google.gson.ParseException: Encountered "\"" at line 1, column 113."